# Zend Studio 7 - code template source?

Tags: zend-studio

Is there a code template gallery for Zend Studio 7?

I used to use Zend Studio 5.5 but since they moved onto eclipse, I haven't found the time to adapt to it. I remember Zend Studio 5.5 came with code templates for generating php docblocks and other things but Zend Studio 7 seems to come by default with nothing, giving you the option to add these in.

Where could I find code templates? And for that matter, where could I find Zend Studio 7 resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Studio 7 documentation: http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio-7/zend-studio-7.htm

It doesn't look like there is a de-facto template source. Most of these templates will need to be built by yourself.

For importing and exporting templates, here is the documentation.

http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio-7/templates.htm#Adding_new_templates

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will have to export your templates from ZEND Studio V5.5 and import them into ZEND Studio v7.  Instructions for doing this are located [here](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio-7/code_templates_preferences.htm)

Answer (score -1):

If you were happy with the templates in Zend Studio 5.5, why not just export those and import them into ZS 7?